# Accessing CSS elements via Javascript & the CSS javascript/DOM Gap

Tags: javascript, css, dom

My question is why doesn't CSS inject an element's property into the DOM? What am I missing.

I have been trying to retrieve the height property using the "document.getElementById" method and I seem to be in two different worlds.

The height property initially is set by CSS as in the example below:

```
<style ...>
      #div_ele { height: 100px; }
</style> 

<script ...>
      alert(document.getElementById("div_ele").style.height);
</script>
```

The "offsetHeight property is browser specific and doesn't work in webkit-type browsers. I don't care for Jquery, so I'm looking for a pure javascript solution.

Please give your insight on this gap between CSS and the DOM. Also, any javascript solution that will work across browsers are welcomed.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `offsetHeight` doesn't work in webkit browsers. I do use Chrome and it does work. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/RhYNL/).

Comment: Maybe my version of Chrome is too old; I'll recheck it. I'm using "Version 21.0.1180.90". But I wanted something to work in older browser too. I did find another solution posted below. But I do thank you for your participation and consideration.